# react lifecycle events stops after componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

i have created starter project with create-react-app command. and added two lifecycle events, componentDidMount() works fine but componentWillReceiveProps() props not firing.

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App appState={appState} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <EasyABC appState={this.props.appState} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

EasyABC.jsx file:

```
     @observer
export default class EasyABC extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.appState.index=0
        let letterSound = document.querySelector("audio[data-key='letter']")
        letterSound.play()
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(){//never stops here
        debugger
    }...
```

if its needed; package.json:

```
{
  "name": "assasment1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "mobx": "^3.2.0",
    "mobx-react": "^4.2.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "custom-react-scripts": "0.0.23"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I searched on net but couldnt find any solution..

Comment: Add `componentWillUnmount` to see if it was unmounted after the first render and let us know the result of that

Comment: @MotiAzu I tried it, never step into there also

Comment: Note that `componentWillReceiveProps()` only fires when you send in **new** props. It does not fire when the component is being mounted, nor immediately after.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps will be called when child component recieves props from parent component .You can create a child component and pass props from your App component and inside child component write componentWillReceiveProps method.You will see debugger stopping there.

Comment: but  i am already doing this, let me update it with origin post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u should read one more [Lifecycle Of React Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

function `componentDidMount`will be called , if Component runs .

function `componentWillReceiveProps` will be called if Props is updated :)

Hope it is helpful for you ^^

Comment: "function componentWillReceiveProps will be called if Props is updated :)" Eventhough upper post helps a lot, This is what i exactly looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`componentWillReceiveProps` will only fire on subsequent renders, not the first one. As far as I can see, you are not updating any props or state in your application.

If you add a counter and a button to increase a state prop, you'll see the `componentWillReceiveProps` function fire:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { count: 0 };

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    debugger; // <-- will now fire on every click
  }
  onClick() { 
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>Clicked {this.state.count} times</button>
    );
  }
}
```

`componentWillUnmount` will only fire whenever you actively unmount the component - which will never happen in your example. If you add i.e. routes or some component that will unmount at some point, you can get this function to trigger as well.

Have a look at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) for more details.